# Append Image In Tiled Pieces to D3.js Grid

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, visualization

I'm trying to append an image within a d3.js svg element in pieces to make up a 12x12 grid. I have my 12x12 grid, but can only figure out how to upload the entire image within each grid section rather than appending the image in pieces to create one tiled image at the end. Any thoughts on how this can be solved would be appreciated, thanks.

Note: the data in the csv file is just coordinates that would make up a 12x12 grid.

```js
var data = d3.range(36).map(function(i) {
  return {
    x_coordinate: (i % 6) * 12,
    y_coordinate: Math.floor(i / 6) * 12,
  };
});
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 1,
    bottom: 15,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  width = 350,
  height = 350;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#tile_photo")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Labels of row and columns -> unique identifier of the column called 'xCoordinate' and 'yCoordinate'
var xCoordinate = d3.map(data, function(d) {
    return d.x_coordinate;
  }).keys(),
  yCoordinate = d3.map(data, function(d) {
    return d.y_coordinate;
  }).keys();

// Build X and Y scales and axis:
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(xCoordinate)
  .padding(0.025),
  y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .domain(yCoordinate)
  .padding(0.025);

// adding the 12x12 rects that will make up the tile photo
var tileImage = svg.selectAll()
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return d.x_coordinate + ':' + d.y_coordinate;
  })
  .enter();

tileImage.append("svg:image")
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x_coordinate)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y_coordinate)
  })
  .attr("rx", 0)
  .attr("ry", 0)
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://via.placeholder.com/72");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="tile_photo" align="center"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're only interested in the visual part, you can do this by adding the image only once and using [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath). This creates a filter that is laid over the image and only allows the pixels at specific places to be shown.

I'm not sure if this would allow you to detect clicks on the individual tiles. If you want that, I actually recommend using a server to slice and serve up the image in tiles for you.

```js
var data = d3.range(36).map(function(i) {
  return {
    x_coordinate: (i % 6) * 12,
    y_coordinate: Math.floor(i / 6) * 12,
  };
});
// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {
    top: 1,
    bottom: 15,
    left: 0,
    right: 0
  },
  width = 350,
  height = 350;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#tile_photo")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Labels of row and columns -> unique identifier of the column called 'xCoordinate' and 'yCoordinate'
var xCoordinate = d3.map(data, function(d) {
    return d.x_coordinate;
  }).keys(),
  yCoordinate = d3.map(data, function(d) {
    return d.y_coordinate;
  }).keys();

// Build X and Y scales and axis:
var x = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, width])
  .domain(xCoordinate)
  .padding(0.025),
  y = d3.scaleBand()
  .range([0, height])
  .domain(yCoordinate)
  .padding(0.025);

var clipPath = svg
  .append("clipPath")
  .attr("id", "crop")
  .selectAll("rect")
  .data(data, function(d) {
    return d.x_coordinate + ':' + d.y_coordinate;
  })
  .enter()
  .append("svg:rect")
  .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
  .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.x_coordinate)
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.y_coordinate)
  });

var tileImage = svg.append("svg:image")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .attr("clip-path", "url(#crop)")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://via.placeholder.com/72");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="tile_photo" align="center"></div>
```